# how to avoid reloading Rad Tree List

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreelist

I am using Telerik Rad Tree List. when expanding the tree , it is postback and get child data from server. it is ok. but when collapse the tree, the page is again reload.

i am not sure, it is default action in telerik tree list.

i am using vs2010 and sql server 2008 for my web application.

How to avoid the reloading while collapse the tree.

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: One would think you would just put the control in an UpdatePanel to prevent the whole page from refreshing and instead refreshing only the RadTree. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The TreeList will still have to do a postback when you expand because the parent node's children get created on expand. I believe this is how it loads -- I am facing the same problem actually. But if you want to decrease time it takes to reload the page, you can "ajaxify" it. Refer to this link: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-onclientnodeclicking.html

If you really want to get rid of the postback, refer to this link: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-onclientnodeclicking.html
But that's for TreeView, might work on TreeList. I still think it'll go back to the server when you try to structure on the client-side.

Comment: he is not asking about treeview

Answer (score 0):

write the client side onclientnodeclicking event and check if node is expand then write code for collapse.